# Java throwing ClassNotFoundExceptions despite the classes being on build path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have two different java projects (I'll call them project 1 and Project 2 for simplicity's sake) loaded into eclipse, and project 1 is added to the build path of project 2. I have imported the only package in the src folder of project 1 into a test class for project 2, and within the code of that test class I have simple object declarations of classes from project 1 as such:

```
ProjectOneClass object = new ProjectOneClass();
```

This code compiles without error, the compiler recognizes that these classes are on the build path. When I run the code as a Java application via Junit4, though, the program throws ClassNotFoundExceptions when it comes across these lines of code. The code is supposed to print these ClassNotFoundExceptions to the error log, but for some reason nothing is being printed. I'm using a simple

```
try {
    ...
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

structure, so I don't know why it's not printing to the error log.

The JUnit printout is simply:

```
Junit execution complete
Summary: 4 succeeded, 3 failed.
```

The four that succeed do not reference the imported project 1 package.

I have tried all manners of changes to the build path configurations, and nothing has shown any promise of improvement. The only thing I can think might be able to fix this is the order of the build path as specified in the Order And Export tab of the build path configuration window. Right now the order is:

```
project 2 packages
EAR Libraries
JRE System Libraries
JUnit4
a few JAR files (c3p0, commons-codec, ojdbc6)
project 1
```

I don't know for sure if the problem lies here or elsewhere, though. If anyone can help me out with this, I'd be very grateful. Thanks for reading.

Comment: How are you running it, and what does the error output look like?

Comment: Is ProjectOneClass in a JAR file?

Comment: I have edited the post with details on how I'm running it and info on the error log. Project 1 is another project in my workspace, so its classes are not in a JAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Project 1 relies on several JARs that Project 2 doesn't have as part of its build path. I figured that since Project 1 had those JARs set within its build path, it would still work fine. Upon creating instances of classes from Project 1, however, I found that Project 2 required these JARs in its own build path.

This would make sense to me if the classes I was instantiating were implementations/extensions of a class from one of these JARs, but they weren't.

Regardless, by adding a couple of JARs to Project 2 I fixed the problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This may be the case due to the fact that eclipse has different class loader for different projects, so they are not automatically shared. You don't know when a class from a jar file will be needed, this may be very implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Run Configuration for your Project 2 class file.

In Eclipse, you can right click -- Select Run As -- Run Configuration and then in the classpath tab, make sure Project 1 is added by clicking on Add Projects.

Comment: adding the project to the classpath in the run configuration did not fix the issue. I added it as a User Entry, not a Bootstrap entry, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Let's narrow down the problem and see if it relates to a JUnit launch config, or a more general problem involving the two Eclipse projects.

Create a class in Project 2 with a main(String[]) method. In that method, reference one or more of the types in Project 1 that appear to be causing your CNFE's. Run this class using the Java Application launch configuration type.  (I'm assuming from your post that you're having trouble with launches based on the "JUnit Test" Launch Configuration type.) Report back.

Also, I've seen some funny behavior using the JUnit Test launch configuration type with JUnit 4 tests of late, although I don't think it's totally broken. So you could try a JUnit 3 configuration.